# What is causing a circular reference when plotting a map using ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: python, arcgis

Following the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/visualizing-data-with-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/) for the ArcGIS API for Python, I'm attempting to plot coordinates from a spatially enabled dataframe. Perhaps my understanding of a circular reference is off, but I can't see how the object would be referencing itself.

```
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.gis import GIS
## importing geocoded data from pickle
prop_sdf = pd.read_pickle("./recent_geocoded.pkl")
prop_sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_xy(prop_sdf, 'lat','long')
prop_sdf.head()
```

This is what my resulting dataframe looks like:

```
    unique_id        lat       long
0   43432884  41.701011 -70.019244
2   43400770  41.641784 -70.366659
3   43425636  41.701954 -70.146602
4   43427274  41.720506 -70.021849
5   43427818  41.649288 -70.490767
```

I'm able to render the interactive map

```
m1 = GIS().map("United States")
m1.zoom = 4
m1.center = [39,-98]
```

But hit an error when plotting:

```
prop_sdf.spatial.plot(map_widget=m1)
m1
```

Trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-d48a9f223ff4> in <module>
----> 1 prop_sdf.spatial.plot(map_widget=m1)
      2 m1

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_accessor.py in plot(self, map_widget, **kwargs)
   2002             self._data.columns = [c.replace(" ", "_") for c in self._data.columns]
   2003             # plot and be merry
-> 2004             _plot_map_widget(map_widget)
   2005             self._data.columns = orig_col
   2006             return True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_accessor.py in _plot_map_widget(mp_wdgt)
   1984                  colors=kwargs.pop('cmap', None) or kwargs.pop('colors', None) or kwargs.pop('pallette', 'jet'),
   1985                  alpha=kwargs.pop('alpha', 1),
-> 1986                  **kwargs)
   1987 
   1988         # small helper to address zoom level

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_viz\mapping.py in plot(df, map_widget, name, renderer_type, symbol_type, symbol_style, col, colors, alpha, **kwargs)
    191         fc.layer['layerDefinition']['drawingInfo']['renderer'] = renderer
    192         if map_exists:
--> 193             map_widget.add_layer(fc, options={'title':name})
    194         else:
    195             map_widget.add_layer(fc, options={'title':name})

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\widgets\_mapview\_mapview.py in add_layer(self, item, options)
   1051              _is_geoenabled(item):
   1052             item = item.spatial.to_feature_collection()
-> 1053         self._add_layer_to_widget(item, options)
   1054 
   1055     def _add_layer_to_webmap(self, item, options):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\widgets\_mapview\_mapview.py in _add_layer_to_widget(self, item, options)
   1091             # (i.e., do what was done for ImageryLayer for all major Layers)
   1092             # 'No type' layer just means that we'll figure it out at JS time
-> 1093             _lyr = _make_jsonable_dict(item._lyr_json)
   1094             if ('type' in _lyr and \
   1095                 _lyr['type'] == 'MapImageLayer') and \

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\widgets\_mapview\_mapview.py in _make_jsonable_dict(obj)
     60         will later be used to delete all values with this value"""
     61         return flag
---> 62     dict_ = json.loads(json.dumps(obj, default=default_func))
     63     return { k:v for k, v in dict_.items() if v != flag }
     64 

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

ValueError: Circular reference detected
```